# How can you figure out if Column A contains something from Column B?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've been trying to figure out a way to grab information from Table A Column A compared to Table B Column A, for example:

```
TableA
Name
abcd_1234_efgh
zxcdde_gets_3214_
jkil_uelso_5555_aseil
uuuu_kkkk_iiii_3333

TableB
ID    
1234          
3214           
5555      
3333
```

I've tried doing an INNER JOIN from Table A to Table B then doing a WHERE TableA.A LIKE TableB.B, but I think I'm missing a section to make it work.

```
SELECT
    a.Name,
    b.ID
FROM
    TableA a

INNER JOIN
    TableB b
ON
    a.Name LIKE CAST(b.ID AS STRING)
```

The result I want from it is:

```
Name                      ID
abcd_1234_efgh            1234
zxcdde_gets_3214_         3214
jkil_uelso_5555_aseil     5555
uuuu_kkkk_iiii_3333       3333
```

But currently I'm getting nothing as a result. I believe I'm missing something or might be thinking of the wrong way to go about getting the result needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Maykid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.  I think this will work in BigQuery:

```
SELECT a.Name, b.ID
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.Name LIKE CONCAT('%', CAST(b.ID AS STRING), '%');
```

But you may really want:

```
SELECT a.Name, b.ID
FROM TableA a CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(SPLIT(a.Name, '_')) namepart JOIN 
     TableB b
     ON namepart = CAST(b.ID AS STRING);
```

This looks like each part of the name separately and allows BigQuery to do an equality join -- which should be more scalable.

Comment: Exactly what I needed and both work perfectly, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.tableA`
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.tableB`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(Name, id)
```

you can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.tableA` AS (
  SELECT 'abcd_1234_efgh' Name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'zxcdde_gets_3214_' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jkil_uelso_5555_aseil' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'uuuu_kkkk_iiii_3333' 
),  `project.dataset.tableB` AS (
  SELECT '1234' id UNION ALL          
  SELECT '3214' UNION ALL           
  SELECT '5555' UNION ALL      
  SELECT '3333' 
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.tableA`
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.tableB`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(Name, id)
```

with result

```
Row Name                    id   
1   abcd_1234_efgh          1234     
2   zxcdde_gets_3214_       3214     
3   jkil_uelso_5555_aseil   5555     
4   uuuu_kkkk_iiii_3333     3333
```

Note: using `REGEXP_CONTAINS` gives you quite a power of regular expressions but it is a little expensive so instead you can use `STRPOS()` as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.tableA`
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.tableB`
WHERE STRPOS(Name, id) > 0
```

> Quick Update:

I just realised that `id` is not a STRING but rather INT in your question  - so:

`REGEXP_CONTAINS(Name, id)` should be replace with `REGEXP_CONTAINS(Name, CAST(id AS STRING))`
and same for `STRPOS(Name, id)`

Comment: Both versions work perfectly for me, I wish I could give multiple correct answers because both work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Given your data structure, maybe something like this helps (note the application of `SAFE_CAST`):

```
select name, c, t2.number from (
  select t1.name, split(t1.name, "_") splitted from TableA t1
), unnest(splitted) c
left join TableB t2 on t2.number = SAFE_CAST(c as int64)
where number is not null
```